# Prevent Firefox from autocompleting any form with password field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, autocomplete, forms

We have a Single Page Application, built with AngularJS. Like many apps we have a login form with one `input[type=text]` (email) and one `input[type=password]` (password). Alright. Firefox saves the data (if the user confirms) and can autocomplete the form next time.

We also have a form for editing or creating a user. Of course there are input fields of type `text` and `password`, too. Firefox autocompletes these fields in any case for any user.

Our user edit form:

```
<!--span>made by selectize directive: no id, no name<span-->
<input type="text" tabindex="0"></input>
<input
    id="whatever"
    autocomplete="off"
    class="form-control"
    name="hi"
    ng-minlength="settings.loginSettings.passwordMinLength"
    ng-model-options="{debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0}}"
    ng-model="userData.password" 
    ng-required="!userData.id" 
    placeholder="{{ '_settings.password' | translate }}" 
    type="password" />
```

Our form has a different `id` than the login form, it has the `autocomplete="off"` attribute ([which is turned off in FF >= 30](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion), [although it is apparently HTML5 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-form-autocomplete)) and the password field has different `name` and `id` attributes than the one in the login form.
Other suggestions, like adding one more hidden (`style="display: none"`) text input field do not work.

---

I've created a very dirty JS hack in the user edit controller, which empties the dirty fields and the related model fields, but the user does see strange things going on on the page.

[Most](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2186325/2092322) [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/582244/2092322) of this issue here are quite old, but on the other hand tons of apps have a login form **and** a user editing form. I guess we are missing something simple here?

*Thanks for any advice!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed same issue by adding fake fields **above** real fields.

```
<input id="prevent_autofill" type="text" style="display:none;" value="" name="prevent_autofill"></input>
<input id="password_fake" type="password" style="display:none;" value="" name="password_fake"></input>

<input id="real_login" type="text" value="" name="real_login"></input>
<input id="real_password" type="password" value="" name="real_password"></input>
```

Comment: Right, I've ended up doing the same. This seems to be the most proper solution at this point. But, I mean, seriously?

Answer (score 3):

This is an old thread but another solution would be to set `autocomplete='new-password'` in the input field.

```
<input
 id="whatever"
 autocomplete="new-password"
 class="form-control"
 name="hi"
 ng-minlength="settings.loginSettings.passwordMinLength"
 ng-model-options="{debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0}}"
 ng-model="userData.password" 
 ng-required="!userData.id" 
 placeholder="{{ '_settings.password' | translate }}" 
 type="password" />
```

see [MDM web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#Preventing_autofilling_with_autocompletenew-password)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way in modern browsers is to set `autocomplete="new-password"`

More details may be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion).

i.e.

```
<input
    id="whatever"
    autocomplete="new-password"
    class="form-control"
    name="hi"
    ng-minlength="settings.loginSettings.passwordMinLength"
    ng-model-options="{debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0}}"
    ng-model="userData.password" 
    ng-required="!userData.id" 
    placeholder="{{ '_settings.password' | translate }}" 
    type="password" />
```