# Impossible to disable the Google autofill / autocomplete on form fields

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, autocomplete, autofill

I'm currently trying to remove Google autofill / autocomplete on my form.
I already have autofill using google map, but navigator autofill comes to put himself on top of the other one
I tried a lot of solutions found on the others topics.

- adding autocomplete="off" both form / input
- autocomplete="randomString"
- adding hidden input at the beggining of the form
- replacing both id and name attribute by random string

My input tag looks like :

```
<input id="Ju6wJZPEnc" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="ENTER_PICKUP_ADDRESS" class="MuiInput-input-32 controls" type="text" name="rRxgEiRXru" onkeypress="return event.keyCode !== 13;" autocomplete="8J%A*yG9eb!F[NLEqv8Q">
```

[image]

Comment: does this keep happening when you remove the "autocomplete" attribute?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186290/disable-autocomplete-via-css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Comment: Rebecca : This happens whether or not I delete it.

Comment: Ty for your links but I already searched and tested a lot of solution gave on stackoverflow, nothing really works