# How to prevent the credit-card number field being cached by the browser

Tags: asp.net, credit-card

I have an input field on a webpage that contains a credit-card number. What is the best way of preventing the browser from caching this value?

Any solution needs to work on a large selection of browsers.

Comment: If by "caching" you mean for field autocompletion, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put attribute `autocomplete="off"` to your html form. E.g.

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off"
  action="http://www.example.com/form.cgi">
[...]
</form>
```

See this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion#How_to_Turn_Off_the_Autocompletion_Feature).

Answer (score 4):

```
<asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="Textbox1" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I can't believe I've not seen that before. I must have been living a bubble! 

Thanks.

Comment: The TextBox has an `AutoCompleteType`, but it doesn't support `off`. Also, womp's comment adds useful details on the subject. If you need this for security, maybe you need more...

Comment: For further information on the `AutoCompleteType` enumeration, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.autocompletetype.aspx).

It might not support, `Off` but it supports `Disabled`.

Comment: @Simon - I did check before I posted, and `Disables` didn't generate `autocomplete` for me. Odd. Possibly because I'm using Firefox/

Comment: I've confirmed this myself. On that basis, I'm going to move the accepted answer to Juha. Thanks for the help!