# which web browsers (and which versions) implement the autocomplete=off feature?

Tags: html, security

I have a web form asking for a credit card number. How can I prevent the browser from saving this information?

I see people proposing to use the `autocomplete="off"` feature.

Which web browsers do implement this feature?

For which versions of those browsers?

**I am looking for a trustful public article with this answer, so that I can rely my decision on it.**

Also, is there a standard javascript snippet to implement this feature in case the browser does not support it?

note: before marking this question as duplicate, please note that I did not find the answer in those stackoverflow's questions: 
[Is there a W3C valid way to disable autocomplete in a HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form) , 
[How to prevent the credit-card number field being cached by the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715171/how-to-prevent-the-credit-card-number-field-being-cached-by-the-browser) , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533032%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: good question but i don't really know. I want say Firefox only recently added support. I know that webkit, ie and opera support. not sure on anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MDN: input element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) the `autocomplete` attribute is supported from these browser versions:

Desktop:

- Chrome 17.0
- Firefox 4.0
- Internet Explorer 5
- Opera 9.6
- Safari 5.2

Mobile:

- Android : unknown
- Firefox Mobile 4.0
- IE Mobile : all
- Opera Mobile : all
- Safari Mobile : all

Answer (score 0):

This may be 4 years old, but it isn't folly to assume that the versions quoted here and above support `autocomplete="off"`.

[Is autocomplete="off" compatible with all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868299/is-autocomplete-off-compatible-with-all-modern-browsers)