# Firefox Remembers Textbox Value in Advance in .NET

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, security, textbox

I have multiple textboxes to enter credit card and security number for it. But I dont want browsers to remember which numbers the customer entered to them.

Note: The page is completely sending ajax request by using javascript for any operations.

Refers to : [Is there a W3C valid way to disable autocomplete in a HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form)

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can use the HTML attribute `autocomplete` with the value `off`.

```
<input ... autocomplete="off" />
```