# Is there a way to prevent browser autofill an input box?

Tags: html, forms

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)
>   [Is there a W3C valid way to disable autocomplete in a HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form)

My browser automatically fills the register form in my website, which is supposed to be anonymous so it's not a very good sign to users to see their names already on the form.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

I could take the input box and simply erase it with javascript but I wanted to know if there was another way round. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

That should work.