# Disabling autosuggestion on WebView?

Tags: android, webview

I have some HTML text inputs into a WebView, and I need to disable the autosuggetions on these inputs from Android, not from HTML (autocomplete=off).

How can I do this?

Comment: here is the main link

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This problem vexed me for quite a while but the solution is very simple:

```
webview.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
```

I wrote about it here:

http://roysutton.com/2012/02/21/preventing-auto-fill-in-android-webview/

Comment: For when webview already has the data: `WebViewDatabase.getInstance(this).clearFormData();`

Answer (score 17):

The suggested above answers didn't help me.
So I found next solution: I just created a simple wrapper for WebView and used it.

```
public class NoSuggestionsWebView extends WebView {
    public NoSuggestionsWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NoSuggestionsWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NoSuggestionsWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        InputConnection ic = super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);

        outAttrs.inputType &= ~EditorInfo.TYPE_MASK_VARIATION; /* clear VARIATION type to be able to set new value */
        outAttrs.inputType |= InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD; /* WEB_PASSWORD type will prevent form suggestions */

        return ic;
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I had the same problem in my app and after applying this, users reported problem solved.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to setSaveFormData setting as False, this also helped me

```
WebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
WebView.clearFormData();
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the above helped so after extensive search i found this which works perfect on webview as well as normal websites. Text area can be replaced by Input text fields too :)

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="comments" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off"  spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution of @lpsun in Kotlin.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.text.InputType
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection
import android.webkit.WebView

class NoSuggestionsWebView : WebView {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs,
        defStyle)

    override fun onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs: EditorInfo): InputConnection? {
        val ic = super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs)

        /* clear VARIATION type to be able to set new value */
        outAttrs.inputType = outAttrs.inputType and EditorInfo.TYPE_MASK_VARIATION.inv()
        /* WEB_PASSWORD type will prevent form suggestions */
        outAttrs.inputType = outAttrs.inputType or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD

        return ic
    }
}
```

Comment: For Android 5 without Google Play Services see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025200/android-view-inflateexception-error-inflating-class-android-webkit-webview/60639991. There is a bug in `appcompat` library, so WebView will crash on these devices.

Answer (score 1):

If it already has the form data then `setSaveFormData(false)` won't stop it from using it.  To clear the database you may have to do the following:

`WebViewDatabase.getInstance(this).clearFormData();`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't do this from Android's side, however in adding to the webview's text input spellcheck="false" did the trick.

```
<textarea spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android 8 and above, you should set importance of a textview subclass for system auto-fill feature:

```
android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"
```

Official reference: [Optimize your app for autofill](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-optimize)

Furthermore, You might try to delete the "Web Data" sqlite file in data/data/{your-app-package}/app_webview when webview isn't in use for security's sake.