# Difference between android:inputType="textPassword", "textVisiblePassword","textWebPassword" and "numberPassword" in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Can anyone explain the differences between the

```
   android:inputType="textPassword",
   android:inputType="textVisiblePassword",
   android:inputType="textWebPassword",
   android:inputType="numberPassword"
```

of EditText ViewGroup in Android Layout?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html

Answer (score 22):

Even though it has been already answered I'll add some more details to the differences in password [InputType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) variations:

1. `android:inputType="textPassword"`: Corresponds to `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD` i.e. it allows you to enter a string that is taken as a password (hidden and preventing autocompletion and suggestions unless set explicitly). This one is mostly used when we want to enter passwords.
2. `android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"`: Corresponds to `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD` and is the same as the previous one but the password is visible (useful if you want to use it to allow to see the password as default because it prevents the autocompletion and suggestions unless they are set explicitly - it is advisable to also have a way to hide the password)
3. `android:inputType="numberPassword"`: Corresponds to `TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD` same as `android:inputType="textPassword"` but you can only enter numbers. Take into account that if you use it the password will not be so strong, so I wouldn't recommend using it when dealing with sensitive data unless it is used along with another type of user authentication.
4. `android:inputType="textWebPassword"`: Corresponds to `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD` and has the same behaviour as `android:inputType="textPassword"` but it is intended to be used in a web form i.e. inside a browser page (any web form control that takes input from a user). So this shall not be used in an `EditText` native control. An example of using this would be to [disable AutoSuggestion from Android in a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28009054/6248510) by wrapping a `WebView` and changing `EditorInfo` input type to add the flag `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD` inside the `onCreateInputConnection`method.

As an example of the last one taken from the link:

```
public class NoSuggestionsWebView extends WebView {
    ...

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs)
    {
        InputConnection ic = super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);

        outAttrs.inputType &= ~EditorInfo.TYPE_MASK_VARIATION; /* clear VARIATION type to be able to set new value */
        outAttrs.inputType |= InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD; /* WEB_PASSWORD type will prevent form suggestions */

        return ic;
    }
}
```

I hope it is clear now the differences and mainly between `android:inputType="textPassword"` and `android:inputType="textWebPassword"`

Answer (score 9):

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

The attribute above will take the password as a string.

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

The one above will make the password text visible.

```
android:inputType="numberPassword"
```

And this one will take a numeric password only.

Comment: what about `textWebPassword`?

Comment: What is the point of "textVisiblePassword" if it doesn't hide the text? Isn't it the same as default

Comment: The system will know it's a password even though it's visible, and it shouldn't be saved in autocomplete dictionary etc.

Answer (score 7):

From [the doc for `android:inputType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType):

> **textPassword**
>   Value: 0x00000081
>   Text that is a password. Corresponds to
>   `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD`.
>
> **textVisiblePassword**
>   Value: 0x00000091
>   Text that is a password that should be visible. Corresponds to
>   `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD`.
>
> **textWebPassword**
>   Value: 0x000000e1
>   Text that will be used as a password on a web form. Corresponds to
>   `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD`.
>
> **numberPassword**
>   Value: 0x00000012
>   A numeric password field. Corresponds to
>   `TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD`.

Comment: what does `web form` means here? a form to be submitted to a web service?

Comment: My answer was copied from official doc. If you can't understand this ask me, before downvoting ... downvotes are not made for this purpose :P

Comment: Where did you get those constants from... I need the entire mapping thanks!

Comment: The official documentation for `textWebPassword` does not explain how a password on a web form is different than a password in a different location.  Neither does it explain how Android handles this differently than `textPassword`.  To correctly answer the question, one would need to address this deficiency in the Android documentation.