# Input type "textVisiblePassword" vs "text": what's the difference?

Tags: android

Short and sweet: I have no idea what the difference between `textVisiblePassword` and `text` is, in regards to `inputType` on an EditText.  According to the docs, `textVisiblePassword` is "text that is a password that should be visible", where password is unhelpfully "text that is a password".

What's the diff?  Why use textVisiblePassword?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454237/difference-between-androidinputtype-textpassword-textvisiblepassword-text

Comment: @AlWang thanks, but has nothing to do with anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `textVisiblePassword` type explicilty tells software keyboard, that content of this field should not be added to any vocabulary, synchronized through network, added to usage statistics or anything like this. It still makes sense to use it for sensitive data, like logins - not exactly secret, but nothing you would share.

Answer (score 1):

when we setup textPassword input type on edit text. textVisiblePassword inputtype is used when we want to have show password option. This option will make the password readable whereas text inputtype won't do this

Comment: So there's no use having textVisiblePassword on its own, it's only useful in conjunction with a 'show password' option?

Comment: Yes. As much I know this the only answer. Accept the answer if u r satisfied

Comment: Thanks. I'll let it run for a bit first :)

Comment: @Tom - using `textVisiblePassword` type explicilty tells software keyboard, that content of this field should not be added to any vocabulary, synchronized through network, added to usage statistics or anything like this. It still makes sense to use it for sensitive data, like logins - not exactly secret, but nothing you would share.

Comment: @tomash make that an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @tomash _The reputation always gets through_