# inputType doesn't hide the password

Tags: android, android-edittext, passwords, android-inputtype

I have set attribute `android:inputType` in `EditText`

```
android:inputType="textWebPassword"`
```

but it still shows the password I'm entering. 
Is there anything else(or instead) that should be done?

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
 android:background="@drawable/background_edit"
 android:ems="10"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:hint="@string/new_pass_hint"
 android:inputType="textWebPassword"
 android:textColor="@color/edit_text_text_color"
 android:textColorHint="@color/edt_text_hint_color"
 android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this please

```
Edttext.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

then this in your layout

```
android:password="true"
```

Comment: It almost fixed it. The first letter is unhidden , and then after typing the second one it is hidden. I will accept your answer anyway, but do you know why it only works after the second letter?

Comment: yeah i know that the first code makes it unhidden,but the second code doesn't work unless you add the first one ..setTransformationMethod is programmatic way to set input type.so we set it  to PasswordTransformationMethod and then choosed if we want to hide it or not in  the layout .Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You must set

`android:password="true"`

Comment: wasn't that deprecated ? Or I'm mistaken?
Thanks.

Comment: Hmm...seems its deprecated.....but isn't it making the password hidden? As I recently used it and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

it should be `textPassword` look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454237/difference-between-androidinputtype-textpassword-textvisiblepassword-text)

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="42dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
 android:hint="Password"
 android:inputType="textPassword"
 android:padding="5dip"
 android:singleLine="true"
 android:textColor="#363435"
 android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Comment: There's not much code , I just used a TextWatcher 
`public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     if(s.length()==0){
      edtPass.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_edit);
     }else {
      edtPass.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_background);
     }`

Comment: I need it textWebPassword because I work with a server that handles all the requests.. but anyway ,nor this or textPassword seem to work for some reason.
I've edited original post to show the xml.
Thanks.