# Disable keyboard cache Android programmatically

Tags: android, android-keypad

How to disable Keyboard cache in Android programmatically for sensitive input fields?

Answer (score 3):

`android:inputType="password"` doesn't cache

Comment: True but that would also hide the input typed right.. Let's say we are talking about creditcard number.. I do not want to hide the input typed

Comment: android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"   and please read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType

Answer (score 1):

To disable to `Edittext` suggestions

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: This will disable suggestions in my input field. What I'm looking for is a setting at my input field level "to prevent caching" so that its not shown as a suggestion elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the best would be:
`inputType="textVisiblePassword"`

An overview is provided at: [Difference between android:inputType="textPassword", "textVisiblePassword","textWebPassword" and "numberPassword" in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454237/difference-between-androidinputtype-textpassword-textvisiblepassword-text/48950491)

(For different inputtypes: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html?hl=en#TextView_inputType)