# How to programatically disable keyboard caching in android

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application where I am dealing with some sensitive data in EditText field. I want to know that is there any way by which I can disable Keyboard caching, so that the information which I type in my app should not be shown as suggestion in other apps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369578/disable-keyboard-cache-android-programatically try this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38369774/603270

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable keyboard cache Android programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369578/disable-keyboard-cache-android-programatically)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "Text Suggestions", to disable edit text suggestions use below attribute:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

Works like a charm. This is will make sure there are no suggestions when typing on the keypad.