# activate password keyboard on android in html input field

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have a field for users to enter some bus routes, but occasionally, alphabets are needed. I noticed that when `<input type="password" />` is in focus, there is a row of numbers above the normal alphabets only keyboard. Is it possible to call this keyboard? Because users need to see what they are typing, so a password field would not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454237/difference-between-androidinputtype-textpassword-textvisiblepassword-text)...You will only put

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

in your edittext box.
And also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712761/edittext-inputtype-values-xml)