# Android keyboard repeating special chars

Tags: android, keyboard, samsung-mobile, rhomobile

I have a problem with my Android application when used with the Samsung Keyboard on Android 6. When the user types a special char, like a dot or an asterisk, the next key is replaced by the last input char.
Example:

When user types:

```
mobile.abc
```

Application receives:

```
mobile..bc
```

Additionally, I recorded a screencast with the behavior: [youtube video](https://youtu.be/wYmJQwn2VyY).

My application is builded with Rhodes/Rhomobile and uses an integrated webkit browser, which the user agent is: `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-A510M Build/MMB29K; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/54.0.2840.68 Mobile Safari/537.36`.

The problem occurs only when the predictive text of Samsung Keyboard is turned on and only in Android 6+. 
I know that it could be an incompatibility between the integrated browser and the samsung keyboard, but I can't ask for all my users to turn it off only for use with my app. So I would like to have a workaround for this.

Thanks in advance by any help

Comment: `Thanks in advance by any help`. In advance thankers will not get help of course.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [bug](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/741073-predictive-text-issue-samsung-gs7-edge-native-email-app.html). Let's hope for a bugfix.

In the meantime, you can disable predictive text this way:

```
public class NoSuggestionsWebView extends WebView {
    public NoSuggestionsWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NoSuggestionsWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NoSuggestionsWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        InputConnection ic = super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);

        outAttrs.inputType &= ~EditorInfo.TYPE_MASK_VARIATION; /* clear VARIATION type to be able to set new value */
        outAttrs.inputType |= InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD; /* WEB_PASSWORD type will prevent form suggestions */

        return ic;
    }
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28009054/474031)

However, I think disabling predictive text for the whole app will hurt UX. Perhaps you can find something in `EditorInfo outAttrs` to identify the problematic fields?

Comment: I have not access to these settings and classes, because I use a framework with these settings closed. But thanks a lot with your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by an update to the Android System WebView that have not been already fixed.
Further the [post on AndroidCentral](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/741073-predictive-text-issue-samsung-gs7-edge-native-email-app.html)  pointed by [gabrielmaldi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40367669/298004), there is [another post](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/738185-repeating-first-letter-when-typing-samsung-galaxy-keyboard.html) referencing the issue.

As of the first post, the WebView version 55.0.2883.36 fixes the problem.