# How to disable autofill traffic on Android

Tags: android, google-api, autofill

I have an `Android` app where it seems that, despite having a `network_security_config` setup, there seems to be requests going to `content-autofill.googleapis.com` in production. This seems to be happening in the text-fields within web pages in some parts of the app where we open them in a `WebView`. This is a problem since we have security requirements that forbid requests to any external service apart from our own.

Is there a way to blacklist `content-autofill.googleapis.com` somehow or disable the auto-fill functionality at the `WebView` or application level? Can this even be controlled?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling autosuggestion on WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404798/disabling-autosuggestion-on-webview)

Comment: have you found a solution for your problem? if so could you share it? we are facing the same issue.