# (Javascript) Can i set "autocomplete=off" for Single Inputbox?

Tags: javascript, input, autocomplete, passwords

Inside a `<form>` I want to use multiple **Password** type fields but.. I want to make **some of them not to be remembering** the value of it.

Normally i can use `autocomplete=off` inside `<form>` tag.
But this affects over every single fields inside.

Edited: **Got Simple Solution Now**
`<input autocomplete="off" ....... />`

Comment: have you tried on a specific element?  `<input type="text" name="whatever" autocomplete="off" />`

Comment: @_@ oh! what a stupid dude i am. Yes! Joseph. It simply works. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can (set `autocomplete="off"` on individual inputs).

Answer (score 1):

You can set `autocomplete` on a single field by using:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Property, new {autocomplete = "off"})
```

If you're using `DisplayForModel` than you will have to create a custom Edit Template.

Comment: @_@ oh! what a stupid dude i am. Yes! yes. It simply works on single element by using `<input autocomplete=off ... />`. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it on individual fields, but it's a non-standard HTMl extension and will cause your pages to fail validation: [Is there a W3C valid way to disable autocomplete in a HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form)