# How to prevent browser from remembering text field content?

Tags: html, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a W3C valid way to disable autocomplete in a HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form)

Is there a way I can prevent a browser from not remembering the content of a text field? The problem is that the field contains a value such as 100, and then gets appended a currency symbol such as € making it `100 €`. If I click on the field, my widget removes the currency and I can edit the bare number, and when I blur it displays the currency again. Everything works fine until you hit F5 and then you end up having `100 € €` because the browser restored the original value `100 €` it had when the reload happened, and the widget re-added it.

Comment: Do you mean something like `AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF` in your input?

Comment: The browser shouldn't be saving anything in any input field on a refresh in the first place... But if you need to, add some jquery to your code.
`$('#input)'.val('');` which will clear the value in the field.

Comment: @stumpx Many modern browser in fact do, especially Firefox...

Comment: Yes it looks Firefox is the major problem. I can't clear the input to "" because it contains data, but neither do I want the browser to remember the changed input value. I'll try `AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For browsers that support it, there's the new [`autocomplete` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-autocomplete). From the link:

> The `autocomplete` attribute is an enumerated attribute. The attribute has three states. The `on` keyword maps to the **on** state, and the `off` keyword maps to the **off** state. The attribute may also be omitted. The *missing value default* is the **default** state.
>
> The off state indicates either that the control's input data is particularly sensitive (for example the activation code for a nuclear weapon); or that it is a value that will never be reused (for example a one-time-key for a bank login) and the user will therefore have to explicitly enter the data each time, instead of being able to rely on the UA to prefill the value for him; or that the document provides its own autocomplete mechanism and does not want the user agent to provide autocompletion values.

...although in the specific case you describe, I think I'd probably just keep the € symbol outside the field's value in the first place. You can put it next to the field, or superimpose it on the field using CSS (for instance, put it after the field in the markup and then use `position: relative; left: -3em`, that sort of thing). But if you really want to prevent the browser's auto-filling, `autocomplete` is one tool for the toolchest.

Comment: @rFactor: Yeah. And I just really hope they use `POST` for that form. Otherwise, that's one heck of a back button side-effect... ;-)

Comment: champ.. great solution 