# How can I prevent IE form auto-fill from filling in a honeypot field?

Tags: security, internet-explorer, spam-prevention

I have implemented honeypot fields on the majority of my client's contact forms in order to prevent spamming. However, I'm noticing that IE's form auto-fill option fills in the honeypot field, and thus triggers my anti-spam logic. How can I prevent this?

I've tried giving the form field a different name - it is currently called `emailConfirmation`, but I've tried `conf_em` and `liame`, and it's still auto-filling. I've also tried moving the honeypot field to the very bottom of the form - nowhere near the existing `email` input.

Comment: is the field invisible? If yes, I don't see why IE would be auto-filling it. If no, then what's "honeypot" about it?

Comment: Yes, the field within a SPAN that is hidden (css: `display: none`), that's what a honeypot field is - a hidden field that bots don't know is hidden, so they fill it in. But IE *IS* auto-filling it.

Comment: Yeah, I simply could not believe that IE is so stupid. What sense does it make to fill in a hidden field? :/

Comment: I apologize it's a text input field that is "hidden" with CSS. It is NOT a `type="hidden"` input.

Comment: That's what I meant. An `<input type="text" />` with `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`. There is absolutely no sense in filling it.

Comment: I think the following page has some good advice on how to avoid this: [disable autocomplete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form)

Comment: The other thought that comes to mind is that you could have a given value for that honeypot field and check against that value. Or does a bot only put in a value when there is no value in the field?

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in the answer David Faber linked to, try adding the [`autocomplete="off"` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the `input` tag.

This is not a standard HTML4 / XHTML attribute, but all major browsers understand it.  And [it *is* standardized in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-autocomplete-attribute).

Comment: Will this still stop bots from automatically entering data into the field?

Comment: It should _not_ stop bots from automatically entering data into the field, which I assume is the point. (To be specific, it will stop well-behaved programs, such as browsers, which understand and respect the `autocomplete` attribute, from automatically filling in the field. But I assume the bots you want to trap are specifically those that do _not_ behave nicely and respect such instructions.)

Answer (score 1):

Give your honeypot field a semi-random name eg. suffix the actual name with a random number. This way it should never be the same name twice and shouldn't be populated by IE.

You might also want to take a look at [cfformprotect](http://cfformprotect.riaforge.org/).  Its got some great features and has helped me with protecting form submissions quite a few projects.

Comment: Thanks, I also am trying to move away from using ColdFusion where ever possible in these forms, since these are simply marketing websites, and right now, the only need for CF is adding data to the client's database, which will soon not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

here is my suggestion for your invisible honeypot filed:
Put autocomplete="off" html tag at the form level.
Putting it at the invisible field level you are identifying your hidden filed and slightly intelligent bot could use this in order to recognize it.
autocomplete tag suportability:
http://help.dottoro.com/lhdwgiwh.php
You should technical probe with your target IE versions (do you need IE 5 and 6 support?).
For your invisible field name use as common name as possible. E.g. country, so bot algorithm will pick it up and filled it with data.

Regards, Karlo.