# INPUT TEXT remove browser default dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, input

how can i remove the focusin dropdown that you see in this image?[image]

by css or javascript? How?

thanks.

Comment: You mean the highlight on the `<option>`?

Comment: nope i mean the dropdown menu

Comment: Are you talking about the autocomplete that the browser's remembers? Or is this a custom control? There is nothing call dropdown menu in HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `autocomplete="off"`:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

However, this is a non-standard attribute for HTML version < 5. In HTML5 you can freely use this attribute, see the reference:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-form-element.html#attr-form-autocomplete

Answer (score 6):

If that's `input` of type `text` then you can do it by specifying attribute `autocomplete`:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Attribute for `<INPUT ...>`

AUTOCOMPLETE = ON | OFF

```
 <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

**Good read**

[How to Turn Off Form Autocompletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)