# suppress auto fill suggestions

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there a way to suppress auto-fill suggestions via javascript. The reason for this is that im stuck with an existing ajax suggestion box and my users are selecting from the wrong suggestion box because the correct one takes a second longer to appear (because of the ajax).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the `autocomplete="off"` attribute. Previously answered here: [Is there a W3C valid way to disable autocomplete in a HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form)