# How to render the html inside the autocomplet box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have text input and html form. where I put users name and submit to get their information.
Now I have use ajax to show username.

```
<div class="hidesearch" id="search" style="width:"400px;">

                 <input type="text"  id="searchbox"  name="user_name" value=""/>
</div>
```

Problem is when I type text, it shows previous content I submitted in the auto complet options.

What I need is to override the values that shows in the auto-complete and render the names in the auto complete area from ajax call.

```
 function wpay_search() {
 // echo 'Sasi is  a t est';
    global $wpdb;
    $name=$_POST['user_name'];
    $employee=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT `First_Name` FROM table_list WHERE First_name LIKE '$name%' ");

    foreach($employee as $key=> $value){

     echo '<ul>';
     echo '<li>'.$value->First_Name;'</li>';
     echo '</ul>';
  //   echo $value->post_content;

   }


    //wp_reset_query();
    die();
} // end theme_custom_handler
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpay_search', 'wpay_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpay_search', 'wpay_search' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try autocomplete="off" on the input field like this:

```
<input type="text"  id="searchbox"  name="user_name" value="" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Or you can try not using an input field at all. I just use a div in my own Autocompleter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form it says it is a nonstand atribut

Comment: It is valid in HTML5: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and set the attribute [autocomplete to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form) on the input.

Comment: Can't we do it with Jquer ajax ?