# how to keep django login page from remembering credentials

Tags: python, django, authentication, autocomplete

When I first created my login view for my app I used the credentials for a user named jgreen.  Now whenever I open the login page those credentials are automatically filled in and if I enter jgreen into the username field the password field is automatically filled out.  I need this to not happen for obvious security reasons. I tried setting autocomplete on the fields to off, I tried setting autocomplete to off in both the form and fields, this didn't work.  I tried deleting my history, this didn't work either.  Here's my login code.

```
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(...)
```

I'm out of ideas of what to try to prevent this behavior, can anyone provide any assistance or direction?  Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: clarified attempts with autocomplete attribute

Comment: This is more the Browser's doing than Django's.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Comment: as i mentioned above, i already tried to use the autocomplete attribute to fix this problem.

Comment: You have to put in both the fields and the form itself.

Comment: I did put it in both the form and input elements

Comment: I apologize for not clarifying that earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django has nothing to do with the autocompletion. Either your browser, OS, or a third-party password manager is remembering and filling in the data for you. Try using Firefox and following the [remove instructions](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-passwords#w_viewing-and-deleting-passwords). You may want to use the [sqllite manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) to view Firefox's saved password database. You can also [write some javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form) to try and persuade your password manager to not work.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the information, it's good to narrow down my debugging area.