# Problems with input type password in html

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a section in my asp website (After logging in), where user accounts can be added. The problem is that I user inputs of type password and email for the user's email address and password fields. For some reason, it auto populates these fields based on the values it memorized from the login page. The following image presents my scenario. Any suggestions?

[image]

```
<tr>
    <td>Email </td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailToAdd" runat="server" Width="200px" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Department </td>
    <td> 
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboDeptToAdd" runat="server" Width="200px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Position </td>
    <td> 
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboPosToAdd" runat="server" Width="200px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password </td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPasswordToAdd" runat="server" Width="200px" TextMode="Password" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Confirm Password </td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPasswordConfirmToAdd" runat="server"    Width="200px" TextMode="Password" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td><asp:Button ID="btnAddUser" runat="server" Text="Add User" 
            Width="170px" onclientclick="return ValidateAdd();" 
            onclick="btnAddUser_Click" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Comment: it is already in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form

Comment: It is because of your browser's autocomplete behaviour. Not about your program.

Comment: How can I go about disabling this programatically?

Comment: @ReidGarwin You do not want to access `autocomplete` directly from `textbox` since it is a server control. However, you can use `AutoCompleteType`. See my answer.

Comment: Clear your browser history , Then check !

Comment: Look : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17973935/1193035

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `AutoCompleteType="Disabled"` for ASP.Net TextBox control.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailToAdd" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled">
</asp:TextBox>
```

It will render as

```
<input name="txtEmailToAdd" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="txtEmailToAdd" />
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autocompletetype.aspx) is the more information about AutoCompleteType Property.

Comment: I think . this is for correct answer . or clear your browser history !!!

Comment: @RameshRams Clearing browser history is not even an option, because we cannot access or control client's browser.

Comment: This is a browser issue !! if you click the save the values option in browser .it's shown .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17973935/1193035

Comment: @RameshRams ***Autofill forms and saving password are totally two different things*** *(Please look at browser's setting)*. Besides, you cannot ask everyone to clear browser cache and disable autofill before accessing your website; it'll piss off your users.

Answer (score 1):

Just give different names for the input

```
<input type="text" name = "email_to_add_user"/>
```

Comment: This is a valid solution except for the password fields that needs to be masked. Any alternative suggestions on how to mask them?

Comment: Hey The OP have asp.net text box !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML5 then you can disable form auto-completion by using the autocomplete attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="id1" autocomplete='off'/>
```

Comment: Thanks, This does work with HTML5. Unfortunately not for HTML <5

Comment: @abhi ha ha . Very funny  answer . The OP have asp.net textbox(<asp:TextBox ID="txtPasswordToAdd" runat="server" Width="200px" TextMode="Password" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>) , how do you asked to html???  ...

Comment: @RameshRams I don't understand your English? What does "how do you asked to html" mean? HTML attributes can be defined on on server-side controls as well. What's the problem you are having? And why the downvote? Do you have any other better solution or just trolling?

Comment: I have already meat the problem !!!! It's not a autocomplete problem.it's a browser problem.. The OP have asp.net textbox. but your answer is html textbox with html 5 ? what's tha link between asp.net textbox and html input field ?? is it same????

Comment: @RameshRams please think before commenting. Yes. they are the same. The server controls are rendered as html elements only. You can define any html attribute on a server-side control as is. Moreover, the Op asked if he could do it programatically. See his 4th comment on his question- "How can I go about disabling this programatically?". Please first read everything before you just start putting your comments everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the browser auto filling the form fields. Try disabling that option in your browser.

Comment: I need it to be enabled for the login form, But not for the "Add Users" form.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you send the `model` used for `log in page`. If you have `@Html.EditorFor` or `@Html.TextBoxFor` in your `View` it autocompletes with the `value` from your `model`.

Put `value=""` attribute on your text fields

Comment: @Kosmo OP is using traditional ASP.Net (not ASP.Net MVC).

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor . wooow... You go to MVC.. lol.. what a fun !! !!!!  But the OP asked for asp.net webform ,  not a Razor view !!