# autocomplete="off" force in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, autocomplete

I have a login form and I NEED to force autocomplete to off.
i have tried

jquery: `$('#login').attr("autocomplete", "off");`

HTML: `<input ... autocomplete="off">`

Javascript: `document.getElementById('myInputId').autocomplete = 'off';`

When I click the login input box a drop down appears 
across all browsers 
`FF, Chrome, IE..`

N.B. this applies to users who have previously saved password information They need to forced to enter login details

Comment: The `<input ... autocomplete="off">` should work across the modern browsers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29582380/4462191 duplicate

Answer (score 10):

Or add with jQuery: `$("input, select, textarea").attr("autocomplete", "off");`

Answer (score 2):

The [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp) states (tested):

```
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" />
```

Please note that this is defined in HTML5

For previous version see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form)

Comment: The word 'HTML documentation' and then a link to W3Schools has me worried.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag please follow this link

Answer (score 2):

Worked for Chrome onFocus remove readonly - but onBlur you 
have to re-write it.
So:

```
onFocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"
onBlur="this.setAttribute('readonly', true);"
```

This did the trick. For IE and Firefox I added in any case the `autocomplete="off"` with jQuery on "ready" function to all fields that might need it (marking them with a class (or cssclass):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".noautocomplete").attr("autocomplete", "off");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

1. Add disabled attribute to the form fields( email, password, etc.)

   ```
   syntax: <input type="email" name="email" class="email" autocomplete="off" disabled />
   ```
2. On Page Load enable the fields after few miliseconds.

   **use the below JS CODE.**

   ```
   function getRidOffAutocomplete(){

       var timer = window.setTimeout( function(){
           $('.email').prop('disabled',false);
           clearTimeout(timer);
          },
          800);
   }

   // Invoke the function, handle page load autocomplete by chrome.
   getRidOffAutocomplete();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( document ).on( 'focus', ':input', function(){
        $( this ).attr( 'autocomplete', 'off' );
    });
});
```

Or this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input").attr("autocomplete", "off");
});
```

On the other hand, you might have a look at this [Chrome Browser Ignoring AutoComplete=Off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off).

Answer (score 0):

Enclose "form-group" class in form tag  and add onSubmit handler with event.preventDefault() method called inside the handler.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute autocomplete="off" should work in all major browsers.

```
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" />
```

And if someone looking for the `react-semantic-ui` solution like me, this should do the trick:

```
<Form.Input autoComplete='new-password' type="password" />
```

Will render:

```
<div class="field">
  <div class="ui input">
  <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password" />
</div>
```

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/3743