# FireFox seems to always cache forms when I don't want it to

Tags: html, caching

I have simple strict HTML 4.01 forms which pass W3C  Validation fine and have the following in the HEAD section of the form :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="Tue, 18 Mar 1997 00:00:00 GMT">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
```

Regardless of this I end up seeing cached data in firefox for the forms.  I don't see how this could be an Apache issue given that it isn't the servers job to determine if a page may be cached or not.  The browser should simply fetch the page as requested.  Shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reasonable solution for the moment seems to be this :

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="Tue, 18 Mar 1997 00:00:00 GMT">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate">
```

No promise that will stay working as the browser makers of the world seem to follow whatever rules are in fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not caching, but the autocomplete.  Have you tried this?

```
<form autocomplete="off" [other form stuff here]>
```

Because you are worried about W3C, check out this answer: [is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form).  I agree with the accepted answer that this is one place in which breaking W3C is a good idea.

If you really can't break W3C, you should just use https: protocol and that will stop the browser from autocompleting.

Comment: prior to HTML5 was never part of an official standard?  bah ... I can not use HTML5 here

Comment: yep .. just checked .. it breaks the form w3c compliance .. therefore not acceptable