# Form autocomplete is still working even it has been set to "off" MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

I'm using MVC4 in my web application. I have issue with autocomplete in a specific page that remembers the login credential upon login even if I set autocomplete="off" but it still working. Please help. How to turn off the autocomplete. I also tried adding html attribute to each textbox/EditorFor field but no luck. Autocomplete form is still working. Here's the screenshot of my page and view.

**Page as seen in browser**

[image]

**View**

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(
    model => model.idName, 
    new { @class = "className", autocomplete = "off" }
)%>

or you can disable with javascript using
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:text,form").attr("autocomplete","off");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this with jQuery. first put this code just before your div class="row=fluid"

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  function removeAutoComplete(){
  $("input:text").attr("autocomplete","off");
  }

 window.onload=removeAutoComplete;
 </script>
```

This should help with your case.