# How to disable an autocomplete in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

My login.jsp page contain two input tag.One is text input another one is password.
In this page i enabled autocomplete.

```
<form name="login" autocomplete="on">
```

Once user login browser automatically enable autocomplete option.
My problem is after logout user goto signup page the email and password box is auto filled.
But this page i did not enabled autocomplete

```
 <form name="signup" autocomplete="off">
```

How to solve this.

Signup page code:

```
<form action="/signup" method="post" name="signupform" autocomplete="off">    
<input style="width: 80%" type="text" tabindex="2"placeholder="Enter email" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off">
<input style="width: 80%;" type="password" tabindex="3"placeholder="8 character password" name="password"  autocomplete="off" id="password" maxlength="20">
```

Comment: put also on the input like this :  <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">

Comment: This one also i try it but did not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a W3C valid way to disable autocomplete in a HTML form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form)

Comment: There is your answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form

Comment: Here is even longer discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag