# How to remove auto fill and autocomplete form

Tags: jquery, html

How to remove auto fill and autocomplete form

I used autocomplete="off" not work

[image]

please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a W3C valid way to disable autocomplete in a HTML form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this assuming you want to remove all of the autocomplete in your form.

```
 $("body").find('input, form').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Care to explain on how it is not working for localhost?