# How to make autocomplete=off work in login/password field in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, autocomplete, passwords

I want to prevent browsers from storing and showing input values. This is how I do this:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="login" />
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" name="pswd" />
...
</form>
```

But for some insane reasons browsers keep storing and showing values, even if I completely clear browser history. So, I wonder why `autocomplete="off"` is not working. Probably, there is another, more proper way to do this. PS. I'm not sure whether it is important or not, but I'm using `jquery` to build my form.

**EDIT**

And by the way, contrary to official W3C [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#autofilling-form-controls:-the-autocomplete-attribute), in HTML5 `autocomplete="off"` is not respected (at least in FF).

Comment: Even `value=""` does not help.

Comment: Isn't a duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Comment: which browser version are you using?

Comment: @ Deepak Biswal. FF 40.0.3. Ubuntu OS.

Comment: @ Dmytro Pastovenskyi. It seems like all threads prior to 2011 are outdated. There should be some other technique in modern browsers to implement the desired behaviour

Comment: Have you tried in privacy mode? Submit a form, access the page again (without exiting the window) and check if the browser has remembered the values.

Comment: @ Burgi . When I go to a privacy mode, I see that by default inputs are empty (different to what I see in a normal mode). However, when I start typing something, I see a drop-down list with previous logins

Comment: @Burgi. However there is one difference, is that if I type a new login and new password, it will not be stored. But I wish I could do this programmatically, without forcing users to use privacy mode every time when they login to the application.

Comment: @Jacobian my thought is that your dev machine might have remembered the entries from the fields _before_ you added the autocomplete attribute

Answer (score 7):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields:

> [...] many modern browsers do not support autocomplete="off" for login fields.
>
> - if a site sets autocomplete="off" for a form, and the form includes username and password input fields, then the browser will still offer to remember this login, and if the user agrees, the browser will autofill those fields the next time the user visits this page.
> - if a site sets autocomplete="off" for username and password input fields, then the browser will still offer to remember this login, and if the user agrees, the browser will autofill those fields the next time the user visits this page.

While the reasoning behind this is debatable, it's intended behavior.

Comment: It seems like the most relevant answer. But is there any alternative to no longer working autocomplete="off"?

Comment: I personally haven't tried circumventing that behavior, so I can only speculate. What might work is _not_ having the username, password and submit button inside a form and (on button click / enter) using javascript to copy the username and password to a hidden form, then submitting programmatically. Altough I generally think circumventing intended behavior is a bad idea and will cause problems down the line, like users complaining that their form somehow doesn't behave the way they're used to.

Answer (score 3):

Modern browsers with a builtin password manager ignore `autocomplete="off"` in login forms (usually specifically forms with a `<input type="password">`). When the enduser logs in for the first time via such a form, the browser will ask the enduser whether to remember the login for this site or not. If the enduser chooses *No*, then default behavior will continue (so `autocomplete` attribute will be respected, regardless of its value). However, if enduser chooses *Yes*, then default behavior will be overriden and it will behave as if `autocomplete` is *always* turned on. This is a browser configuration setting which is by default on. This is also mentioned in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion).

You can work around this by simply using **Ajax** to submit the form. In other words, instead of using a "plain vanilla" synchronous HTML POST form, make use of `XMLHttpRequest` (if necessary indirectly via e.g. jQuery or equivalent). The current browsers don't recognize a login via Ajax and therefore won't ask the enduser to remember the login.

In case your web framework doesn't offer builtin Ajax facilities, then consider throwing in [jQuery](http://jquery.com). It's then a matter of below lines to unobtrusively enhance an existing form. The below basic kickoff example assumes that you've reworked the server side to return plain text `true` or `false` as response, depending on whether the login was successful or not. You could if necessary conditionally respond depending on the value of `X-Requested-With` header:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#loginFormId", function() {
    var $form = $(this);

    $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize(), function(response) {
        if (response) {
            window.location = "home.html"; // Redirect to homepage.
        } else {
            $("#errorMessageId").text("Unknown login, please retry");
            $form[0].reset();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

autocomplete="off" and autocomplete="false" seems to not work both for chrome and firefox, you could write anything apart from these two like autocomplete="none" this will work.
Go through below links:
[Chrome automcomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775041/disable-autofill-in-chrome-63)
[disabling-chrome-autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Comment: Works like a charm, now that `autocomplete="new-password"` isn't working anymore...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Chrome? 
Maybe this [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153) is relevant, particularly this [comment](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c29).

The comment states

> autocomplete="off" is NOT respected for Autofill data, whether saving
>   or filling. You can see your Autofill data in
>   chrome://settings/autofill. It includes addresses and credit cards.
>
> autocomplete="off" still IS respected for Autocomplete data, both
>   saving and filling. I know the terminology is confusing. Autocomplete
>   data simply tries to match the name attributes. So if you have entered
>   "user@example.com" into an input with name="email" in the past, and
>   Chrome sees another name="email" input, Chrome will offer to complete
>   that data. However, autocomplete="off" will stop this from happening.

[caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=autocomplete) is a good resource as well for checking which browsers support a given feature.

Comment: The questioner mentioned that he is using FF

Comment: @Burgi - In my defense, they hadn't when I started typing my answer.

Comment: I should have checked the timestamps, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be
removing the `""` on `autocomplete` and on `name` because they're properties not values.

```
<form autocomplete="off">
 <input type="text" name="login" />
 <input type="password" name="pswd" />
</form>
```

Comment: In a real case, there are no quotes and still it is not working. Browser keeps remembering it.

Comment: it depends on your browser... some browser don't support that property.

Comment: Then how to mimic this functionality? How to prevent browsers from storing and showing input values (in a drop-down list)?

Comment: @Jacobian are you using HTML5 Doctype?

Comment: Yes, I'm using HTML5 Doctype

Comment: check this link.. this might solve your problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form

Answer (score 0):

Workaround to prevent browsers to fill in the password but using "password" type...

Try with: `<input type='text' ... onfocus=' this.type="password" ' autocomplete='off'/>`

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but if `autocomplete="off"` isn't being respected by the browser, wich is the case by many modern browsers, i always use `autocomplete="new-password"`. Be sure to add this as the first property of the input element.

[Read all about it on this MDN Web Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#Preventing_autofilling_with_autocompletenew-password)