# Disable suggestions for HTML input list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, html-input

I want to disable the suggestions for previously entered texts on a `<input type="text" list="stuff">` which provides a drop down list to choose from via a `<datalist>`.

This behaviour causes some entries to be shown twice and sometimes problems occur when selecting them.

I tried `<input type="text" autocomplete="off">` - in Firefox it works just like I want it to but Chrome disables the suggestions from the `<datalist>` as well.

I would be happy for any solution at all even if it involves JavaScript, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a W3C valid way to disable autocomplete in a HTML form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form)

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek this is definitely not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Add autocomplete="off" onto  element;
Add hidden  with autocomplete="false" as a first children element of the form.