# Card number is displaying on UI page, though we set card number field as autocomplete="off" on all latest browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing issue as autocomplete="off" is not working on my UI page.

I have the credit card number field on my UI page, Once I entered all details of the card and clicked on make payment.

The browser asked me that, 'Do you want to save details', I clicked yes.

Then I re-hit the URL, the page is displaying with card number in the card number field.

I read the fire-fox document
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion, the autocomplete will not in all latest browser, but I want to avoid it.

Can anybody please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Where are your code ? Maybe you should read How to ask a good question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form