# How to preventing form element values saved in php

Tags: html, autocomplete

When login with username, password these values saved into browser cache. How to stop this.

Comment: clear browser cache.... !?

Comment: @MarcGiroux I think the correct answer is the [autocomplete attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp)

Comment: Didnt the browser normaly ask for that?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus well you are probably right. Still, OP is very unclear.

Comment: @MarcGiroux Yes, the English might not be up to par but reading it twice usually reveals the true question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a W3C valid way to disable autocomplete in a HTML form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form)

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the auto complete feature, guess that is what you mean?

```
<input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off">
```