# Setting default string got ng-model to blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a user login and registration form.  The default values that are currently showing I think are what my browser has cached.  I am trying to figure out how to get rid of it programmatically so my input boxes are empty.  When I refresh the page I get the image below. I have tried setting the $scope values for the boxes to empty strings, but this does not work when the page is refreshed.
[image]

What should I do so the input boxes are blank.

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="root" ng-controller="userController"> 
    <div class=user>
        <form name="login_form" >
            <h2 class>Login</h2>
            <h3 class = "login_page">UserName</h3>
            <input ng-model="user" type="text" ng-minlength="1" required>
            <h3 class = "login_page">Password</h3>
            <input ng-model="password" type="password" name="password" ng-minlength="4" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" ng-click="login()" >
            <div ng-if ="login_form.$submitted" ng-messages="login_form.password.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
                <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
            </div>
            <p ng-if="error">Username or login is incorrect</p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class=user>
        <form name = "register_form">
            <h2 class>Register</h2>
            <h3 class = "login_page">UserName</h3>
            <input ng-model="reg.name" type="text" required>
            <h3 class = "login_page">Password</h3>
            <input ng-model="reg.password" type="password">
            <input type="submit" value="Register" ng-click="register()" required >
            <p ng-if="small">Password must be at least 5 chars long</p>
            <p ng-if="duplicate">That user name is taken, please choose another</p>
            <p ng-if="correct">Registration Succesfull</p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my js controller code

```
app.controller('userController', ['$scope', '$location', 'userFactory',  function($scope, $location, userFactory){
    index = function(){
        userFactory.set_name(function(returned_data){
            $scope.reg = {name:''};
            erase();
        })
    }
    index();
    $scope.login = function(){
        userFactory.login($scope.user, $scope.password, function(sendUser){
            if(!sendUser.data.error){
                $location.url('/logged_in');
            }else {
                $scope.error = true;
                erase();
            }       
        })  
    }
    $scope.register = function(){
        $scope.small = false;
        if($scope.reg.password.length < 5){
            $scope.small = true;
        }else {
            userFactory.register($scope.reg.name, $scope.reg.password, function(sendUser){
            console.log(sendUser)
            $scope.duplicate = false;
            $scope.correct = false;
            if(sendUser.data.error){
                $scope.duplicate = true;
                erase();
            }else {
                $scope.correct = true;
                erase();
            }
        })
        }
    }
    erase = function(){
        $scope.reg.name = "";
        $scope.reg.password = "";
        $scope.user = "";
        $scope.password = "";
    }

}]);
```

I have also tried ng-init="user=''" in my input tag for user.  That also did not work

Comment: What view engine are you using server-side ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a W3C valid way to disable autocomplete in a HTML form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form)

Comment: @Flint server side I am using express(node).  This is all in the Mean stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser vendors fight with developers, so we haven't good enough solution to prevent autofill. They said that user should disable autofill for site in browser settings;

[Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

One possible approach, which were tested some time ago -
create directive prevent-autofill, which will change input type at link time and reset it back on keyDown

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ng-init="user=''"`

If that doesn't work try this:

```
<input ng-model="password" type="password" name="password" ng-minlength="4" required autocomplete="nope">
```

This is of course disabling browser autocompletion. More details can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

Comment: Added another part. Please check above

Answer (score 0):

> Setting `autocomplete="off"` here has two effects:
>
> - it stops the browser saving field data for later autocompletion on similar forms though heuristics that vary by browser.
> - it stops the browser caching form data in session history. When form data is cached in session history, the information the user has filled
>     in will be visible after the user has submitted the form and clicked
>     on the Back button to go back to the original form page.